# Why a static const variable assigned from offsetof gets an error if it is not marked inline?

Tags: c++, inline, offsetof

For some reason, this code runs **(!)** but with the raised error if I do not add `inline`. And works fine, otherwise. Why so?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#define NAME b

template <typename T>
struct B {
  static const ptrdiff_t shift = offsetof(T, NAME);  // it runs (!) but gives an error
  // inline static const ptrdiff_t shift = offsetof(T, NAME);  // works fine
};

struct A {
  B<A> b;
};

int main() {
  return 0; 
}
```

`offsetof` is underlined with a red squiggly line:

> Offsetof of incomplete type 'A'clang(offsetof_incomplete_type)

Comment: If it runs, then everything is fine. Editors generally aren't 100% correct when looking at the code, since they don't have a full C++ compiler behind them.

Comment: *If it runs, then everything is fine.* Excepting logic errors, of course. Consider your IDE's Code Analysis tool to be a compiler that's allowed to be wrong so long as it is fast enough to give real-time feedback and is right almost all of the time. When you get into templates and tricky macro wizardry that play with the edges of the language , that's where you should start seeing the CodAn tools screwing up.

Comment: I think you should define `shift` out of the class when `A` is complete _or_ make it `constexpr` instead of `const`.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo Oh, That really works!